# How to ask rhetorically or with irony: Do you think I should start doing this?

Tags: particle-と, rhetorical-questions

I would like to translate the following English sentence into Japanese:

`Do you expect me to start jumping up and down (for joy)?`

I approximately know how to translate parts of the sentence, but do not know how to deliver the irony. I am aware that Japanese speakers often say "We do not use irony, it is impolite", but aside of being impolite, I still want to try delivering a tint of irony in the sentence.

So far I came up with two versions:

私が飛んだり跳ねたりし始める**方がいい**と思うか。

私が飛んだり跳ねたりし始める**はず**と思うか？

I know that past form of the verb is preferred before 方がいい, but I am intentionally using the non-past form to deliver irony. I also use the plain form of 思う to sound harsher/ironic.

Do my translations sound natural to any degree?

Comment: Why is this an irony? What is the example situation and the implied message of this? Maybe did he receive a terrible birthday present and want to say "this can't please me"?

Comment: It isn't. The irony for this situation would be saying "Oh, I'm jumping up and down of joy" in a flat, emotionless tone, and without actually jumping.

Comment: I would think that "jumping up and down (for joy)" should probably not be translated literally.

Comment: The expression is close to "Should I start doing cartwheels now?".
A typical scenario.
- Husband: I did laundry today!
- Wife: Should I start doing cartwheels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common construction is -とでも？ or if you want to make it slightly more explicit -とでも思ったか？

> 私が飛んだり跳ねたりし始めるとでも思ったか？

> 私が飛んだり跳ねたりし始めるとでも？

This will be understood with the unsaid "of course I won't".